# Tor browser 7.0.1 crashes with the latest version of Windows 10 Professional

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Clean install of tor browser 7.0.1 on Windows 10 Professional. It fails to start with the following error

> ```
> Faulting application name: firefox.exe, version: 52.2.0.6242, time stamp: 0x00000000
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.1358, time stamp: 0x59327ae2
> Exception code: 0xc06d007f
> Fault offset: 0x000da9f2
> Faulting process id: 0x3fac
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d2f4177fc537ea
> Faulting application path: C:\Temp\tor\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
> Report Id: 6ed262c4-01da-4f01-837f-c8e28f715010
> Faulting package full name: 
> Faulting package-relative application ID:
> ```